# how to create exe of Python Code using opencv with or without py2exe?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, exe, py2exe

i have some Python Code working properly its some kinda simple thing using opencv.
for example

```
import cv2
x = cv2.imread('Dog6.jpg')
cv2.imwrite('new2.jpg')
```

setup.py is

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import cv2
setup(console=['name.py'])
```

but i am unable to create exe of this code with py2exe.
is there another method to create exe of such program ?

Error is 
ImportError:numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Comment: Can you show the error message. What does "but i am unable to create exe of this code with py2exe." mean in detail?

Comment: Error is  ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the line:

```
 import numpy
```

Into your script, i.e the first file and try again.